# $(...).popover is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have looked through quite a few posts on here dealing with this issue, but none of them seem to solve my problem.

I have imported the jQuery and Bootstrap js files in the right order. Things such as bootstrap panels are working perfectly fine for me.

My script imports are like this:

```
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

However, when I try

```
 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

I get the following message in the Chrome console:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function
```

At first I thought maybe popover was not being included in CDN's copy, so I went ahead and downloaded a local copy with all the plugins included from here:

```
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
```

and got the same error message (re-pointed the script tags towards the local js file).

Doing a search for "popover" the bootstrap.min.js file:

```
http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Shows that popover is included in the file.

Comment: are there multiple instances of jQuery

Comment: Just include your bootstrap js, and by removing jquery, and try.

Comment: are you using some other libraries?

Comment: try `jQuery('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();`.

Comment: @stanze that's not going to work, Bootstrap JS plugins **require** jQuery

Comment: @Tushar no it wouldn't. If there were another jQuery included after the Bootstrap JS, `$` would be getting redefined and `$.fn.popover` wouldn't exist.

Comment: @hitman4890, good idea. Try `$() instanceof jQuery` or `$ === jQuery` in the console. They should both return `true`.

Comment: There were multiple instances, which I removed, but the problem was not solved. Removing jQuery throws $ undefined because boostrap relies on jQuery

Comment: @SergueiFedorov just remove the duplicates. You should only have **one** jQuery `.js` file and it **must** be included **before** the Bootstrap `.js` file

Comment: @redbmk both return true

Comment: @Phil I made sure it was included in order. I also removed all duplicates (since I import scripts a little differently from ASP.NET) and the error is still there. Like I said, the rest of the boostrap elements like panels work just fine

Comment: Bootstrap panels are CSS only, they don't use JS. Again, you should only include **one** copy of jQuery **before** Bootstrap's JS file

Comment: @Phil good point. Looking through the page source there is only one copy of jQuery being imported

Comment: @SergueiFedorov can you try `jQuery.fn.jquery` in your browser console and cross check the version you have imported

Comment: @SergueiFedorov also make sure there are no other errors in the console

Comment: @Phil good catch. I missed one of the imports when looking through the HTML. My _Layout.cshtml was importing jQuery separately. I should stop being lazy and use the BundleConfig.cs to manage my JS imports.

Comment: @ArunPJohny you were the one that mentioned it first

Comment: @SergueiFedorov in case of error like this one of the most common cases is duplicate jQuery versions

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thank you very much. Could you please put up the answer so I can give you credit and so other people with a similar issue will see an actual answer?

Comment: This is also where something like require.js can come in handy, to make sure you get the right version of a library even if it is loaded multiple times.

Comment: For those who use AngularJS with popover.js, use `angular.element` instead of `$`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Since you have stated you have included jQuery and the other libraries correctly, 1 possible case is there could be multiple instances of jQuery in the page.

So based on the server technology used, search for a duplicate version of jQuery and if there is any remove them(if not needed else will have to think about [noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) use).

In case of duplicate jQuery instances the problem is the jQuery version to which the plugin is attached might be different from the one which you are accessing to use the plugin at that point the plugin will not be found.

- https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: Cool, for those who use AngularJS with popover.js, use `angular.element` instead of `$`

Answer (score 30):

The order of including bootstrap.js and jquery.js matters. Include the jquery.js BEFORE bootstrap.js

Comment: This should be a comment on an answer or question buddy.
Upvoting you so you'll be a little closer to the 'comment' privilidge.

Comment: This solved it to me, and it also remove another error that says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined" that is was just showing in the console.

Comment: This definitely qualifies for answer since it solved my error. Thanks @Samir Kulkarni.

Answer (score 4):

For Bootstrap 5 onwards this is how you add popovers
Code for Button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mx-2" data-bs-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-bs-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">
      Your Cart(<span id="cart">0</span>)
      </button>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'));
      var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
      return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl);
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are correctly added popover script in the your site.

To fixed the "$(...).popover is not a function" bug. Sometime just add a timer delay can be fix it.

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

**Modify to**

```
setTimeout((function() { 
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
}),500);
```

Sometimes (always) the web page doesn't fully render the content and the POPOVER will gives this error. So, We need 500ms delay starting the popover script. Sometimes 500ms is not enough to wait for rendering, so more delays can be modified as needed.

Even in bootstrap 5 has this issue too

**Conclusion**

POPOVER script starting need waiting whole page completely render.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and checked jquery version. Moving to v1.12 helped me

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me, was making a call to **$.noConflict()** which returned control of $.
That was because some other JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just like jQuery does. During jQuery initialization, there are some old references of $ saved. noConflict() restores them.

```
$noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$("#id").popover('hide');
});
```

Comment: where should I put this code?

Comment: @dapidmini  You may put the code in one of the scripts that you will be using for the page that uses popover.
If you are writing the script on an HTML page, just have one document ready function and inside it the popover method.

Answer (score 0):

This is Happen due to Differ version of bootstrap
In This case use script of same version as your bootstrap

In other case jquery is not recommended. insted use Advance  Css Js

This is also happen cause latest bootstrap doesn'

Comment: Please check the spelling of your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

After hours, I found out that I forgot to attach bootstrap.js file to my page ;)

Answer (score 0):

So based on the server technology used, search for a duplicate version of jQuery and if there is any remove them(if not needed else will have to think about noConflict() use).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32769926)

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked for me .

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
       var popover = new 
         bootstrap.Popover(document.querySelector('.mypopover'), {
         container: 'body'
      })
 });
```