# "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function" RoR - Bootstrap - jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've checked out this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910823/popover-is-not-a-function) because I have a similar problem with rails.
I'm trying to make an AJAX request work (looking up some financial tickers) and I think that I'm ok with my code (at least I hope) but I'm still getting this weird error:

> bootstrap.self-fdc98dee79ee88255e10cac6caa91338165cb76cf0d263744d8d90011fc2ef8f.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (bootstrap.self-fdc98dee79ee88255e10cac6caa91338165cb76cf0d263744d8d90011fc2ef8f.js:3)
>       at fire (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js:3233)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js:3363)
>       at Function.ready (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js:3583)
>       at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js:3618)

Here's my script:

```
var init_stock_lookup;

init_stock_lookup = function() {
  $('#stock-lookup-form').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status) {
    $('#stock-lookup').replaceWith(data);
    init_stock_lookup();
  })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  init_stock_lookup();
})
```

Here's the page:

```
<div id="stock-lookup">
  <h3>Search for stocks</h3>
  <%= form_tag search_stocks_path, remote: true, method: :get, id: 'stock-lookup-form' do %>
    <div class="form-group row no-padding text-center col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <%= text_field_tag :stock, params[:stock], placeholder: "Stock ticker symbol", autofocus: true, class: 'form-control search-box input-lg' %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <%= button_tag(type: :submit, class: "btn btn-lg btn-success") do %>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Look up a stock
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% if @stock %>
    <div id='stock-lookup-results' class="well results-block">
      <strong>Symbol:</strong> <%= @stock.ticker %>
      <strong>Name:</strong> <%= @stock.name %>
      <strong>Price:</strong> <%= @stock.price %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

The gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'
gem 'devise'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'devise-bootstrap-views'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~> 2.1'
gem 'stock_quote'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

and the link to my gitHub repo : https://github.com/Ardzii/finance-tracker

I'm using RoR and Bootstrap (twitter).
What I understand from the SO link I provided earlier is that I'm having jQuery conflicts but I have no idea where and, most of all, how to fix it...

Thanks as usual for your help guys!

------ EDIT . -----------
Here's my application.js for references (I added the //require twitter/bootstrap line thanks the Hieu's answer).

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require rails-ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add `//= require twitter/bootstrap` into your `application.js`

```
...
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
...
```

It's here: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails#using-javascript

Comment: Hey Hieu! Thanks a lot for your help! However your solution didn't quite solved the problem. Now I get an additional error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` and the `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function` is still there. Now I can make the latter go away by deleting the following lines in my application.js : `//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs` but then I get other errors (obviously, jQuery is not properly included anymore). Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Ardzii did you add that line after require jQuery, it should be like this one:
`//= require jquery_ujs //= require twitter/bootstrap`

Comment: Hi again Hieu! Thanks you're the best! It seems to be working although I seem to have further rendering issues that are unrelated. I will work on them now :). Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Hieu! I don't mean to bother you anymore than I already did, but I can't seem to find out why I'm not getting any renders... If, by any chance, you had a few minutes to spare I would love to get your input on the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628771/ajax-rails-request-apparently-lost-no-ui-results

Comment: Hi @Ardzii, I answered your question, please check :)