# AJAX Rails - Request apparently lost - No UI Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I had some [troubles with a JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625552/uncaught-typeerror-popover-is-not-a-function-ror-bootstrap-jquery) request earlier and the solution provided seems to have fixed the problem (since I get not error from the browser's console) however my app doesn't display a thing in the UI. 
Here's how the request is being handled by the server:

```
Started GET "/search_stocks?utf8=%E2%9C%93&stock=GOOG&button=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-19 12:50:13 +0200
Processing by StocksController#search as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "stock"=>"GOOG", "button"=>""}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Stock Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "stocks".* FROM "stocks" WHERE "stocks"."ticker" = ? ORDER BY "stocks"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["ticker", "GOOG"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered stocks/_lookup.html.erb (1084.6ms) [cache miss]
Completed 200 OK in 3002ms (Views: 1114.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Here's my UI (it's a partial):

```
<div id="stock-lookup">
  <h3>Search for stocks</h3>
  <%= form_tag search_stocks_path, remote: true, method: :get, id: 'stock-lookup-form' do %>
    <div class="form-group row no-padding text-center col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <%= text_field_tag :stock, params[:stock], placeholder: "Stock ticker symbol", autofocus: true, class: 'form-control search-box input-lg' %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <%= button_tag(type: :submit, class: "btn btn-lg btn-success") do %>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Look up a stock
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% if @stock %>
    <div id='stock-lookup-results' class="well results-block">
      <strong>Symbol:</strong> <%= @stock.ticker %>
      <strong>Name:</strong> <%= @stock.name %>
      <strong>Price:</strong> <%= @stock.price %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here are the methods:

```
class Stock < ApplicationRecord

  def self.find_by_ticker(ticker_symbol)
    where(ticker: ticker_symbol).first
  end

  def self.new_from_lookup(ticker_symbol)
    looked_up_stock = StockQuote::Stock.quote(ticker_symbol)
    return nil unless looked_up_stock.name

    new_stock = new(ticker: looked_up_stock.symbol, name: looked_up_stock.name)
    new_stock.last_price = new_stock.price
    new_stock
  end

  def price
    closing_price = StockQuote::Stock.quote(ticker).close
    return "#{closing_price} (Closing)" if closing_price
    opening_price = StockQuote::Stock.quote(ticker).open
    return "#{opening_price} (Opening)" if opening_price
    'Unavailable'
  end
end
```

the controller:

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController

  def search
    if params[:stock]
      @stock = Stock.find_by_ticker(params[:stock])
      @stock ||= Stock.new_from_lookup(params[:stock])
    end
    if @stock
      #render json: @stock
      render partial: 'lookup'
    else
      render status: :not_found, nothing: true
    end
  end
end
```

and the JavaScript (AJAX):

```
var init_stock_lookup;

init_stock_lookup = function() {
  $('#stock-lookup-form').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status) {
    $('#stock-lookup').replaceWith(data);
    init_stock_lookup();
  })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  init_stock_lookup();
})
```

OK so, based on that, if I comment the "render partial: 'lookup'" in my controller, uncomment the "render json: @stock" one and handle the request via my browser directly: I get the info I'm looking for. Meaning that the gem and the request are working correctly. 
Once I'm trying to handle the request via AJAX I get nothing... Anybody have a solution? I get the feeling that I'm handling the JavaScript poorly or that maybe I'm missing a gem or something. 
Anyhow, for reference here's my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'
gem 'devise'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'devise-bootstrap-views'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~> 2.1'
gem 'stock_quote'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

And here's a link to my repo: https://github.com/Ardzii/finance-tracker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `remote: true`, you should to use method `respond_to` to handle ajax. This is an example, you can do step by step:

1. Remove `app/assets/javascripts/stocks.js`
2. Edit action `search` in `app/controllers/stocks_controller.rb`

   ```
   def search
     if params[:stock]
       @stock = Stock.find_by_ticker(params[:stock])
       @stock ||= Stock.new_from_lookup(params[:stock])
     end
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.js
     end
   end
   ```
3. Edit `app/views/stocks/_lookup.html.erb`

   ```
   <div id="stock-lookup">
     <h3>Search for stocks</h3>
     <%= form_tag search_stocks_path, remote: true, method: :get, id: 'stock-lookup-form' do %>
       <div class="form-group row no-padding text-center col-md-12">
         <div class="col-md-10">
           <%= text_field_tag :stock, params[:stock], placeholder: "Stock ticker symbol", autofocus: true, class: 'form-control search-box input-lg' %>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
           <%= button_tag(type: :submit, class: "btn btn-lg btn-success") do %>
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Look up a stock
           <% end %>
         </div>
       </div>
       <% end %>
     <div id='stock-lookup-results' class="results-block"></div>
   </div>
   ```
4. Create `app/views/stocks/_stock.html.erb`

   ```
   <% if stock.present? %>
     <strong>Symbol:</strong> <%= stock.ticker %>
     <strong>Name:</strong> <%= stock.name %>
     <strong>Price:</strong> <%= stock.price %>
   <% else %>
     <i>Stock not found</i>
   <% end %>
   ```
5. Create `app/views/stocks/search.js.erb`

   ```
   $("#stock-lookup-results").html("<%= j render 'stock', {stock: @stock} %>");
   ```

Done!!!

Comment: Hieu to the rescue! Thanks a lot my good sir for your help and time!! I'm just wondering, why would you use the respond to in that case? I mean I understand that you're telling the app to use either html or js depending on the client's request but isn't it going to be always js? Then I'm not sure I get the mechanics of the partial. If I'm not mistaken, you're not referencing _stock anywhere...

Comment: If you had a good and recommended tuto or course to learn more I'd be grateful if you could share it! :P

Comment: Hi @Ardzii! First, if you want to render only js, just remove a line `format.html` in `stocks_controller.rb`. Second, i render `_stock.html.erb` in `app/views/stocks/search.js.erb`.

Comment: Thanks Hieu! And sorry for the heavy questionning. As you've guessed by now, I new to this but really into it ... So thanks again for your help!